# PHP delimiters when using preg_match

Tags: php

I have the following line of code.

```
if (!preg_match('^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$', $this->browser_languages[$i]) && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {     
    $this->language = $this->catalog_languages[$key];
    break 2;
```

I know that I need to add the delimiters to the code but whenever I try to add them I get a parsing error.

Please can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: Show how you tried to add delimiters, also post the exact error message please

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. I think I was trying to add '^' as a delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

You want `'!^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$!'` I've added the `!` as the first character in the regex, and the last.

By delimiting the string this way, you can add pattern modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

With delimiters:

```
!preg_match('/^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$/', $this->browser_languages[$i]);
```

And quote `$value`:

```
preg_quote($value, '/');
```

Full code:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(' . preg_quote($value, '/'). ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$/', $this->browser_languages[$i]) && isset($this->catalog_languages[$key])) {     
    $this->language = $this->catalog_languages[$key];
    break 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the delimiters at the start and end of the regular expression:

`'/^(' . $value . ')(;q=[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$/'`

You may also want to use `preg_quote($value)` in case the value has special characters in that could mess up your regular expression and cause an error.